Openmp Tasks for Recursion
I am new to Openmp programming and I have a question regarding task parallelism on recursions
Let's consider this demo C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct timeval t1, t2;

void recursive_task(int level)
{   
    //printf("%d\n", level);
    
    if (level == 0){
        usleep(1000);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        recursive_task(level-1);

        #pragma omp task
        {
             recursive_task(level-1);
        }
        
        #pragma omp task
        {
             recursive_task(level-1);
        }
        
        #pragma omp taskwait
        
        recursive_task(level-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    double time;

    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);

#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp single
        {
            recursive_task(7);
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&t2, 0);

    time = (double)((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000000;
    printf("%.4f\n", time);

    return 0;
}

Each level of recursion does 4 calls, where only the 2nd and the 3rd call can run actually in parallel.
Now i tried this different version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct timeval t1, t2;

void recursive_task(int level)
{   
    //printf("%d\n", level);
    
    if (level == 0){
        usleep(1000);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        #pragma omp task if(0)
        {
            recursive_task(level-1);

            #pragma omp task
            {
                recursive_task(level-1);
            }
        
            recursive_task(level-1);

            #pragma omp taskwait
            
            recursive_task(level-1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double time;

    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);

#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp single
        {
            recursive_task(7);
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&t2, 0);

    time = (double)((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000000;
    printf("%.4f\n", time);

    return 0;
}

The execution also seems to follow the correct ordering of the calls (i think it has to do with if(0) clause).
However what suprised me is that the second one is faster than the first one. I executed with 8 threads and the times where 4.4 seconds for the first approach and 3.4 seconds for the second approach!
What is the main difference that makes the second code faster?

Which compiler and which optimization flags do you use? The 1ms per task is probably not enough to amortize the scheduling overhead of openmp tasks. The second code has less tasks to schedule and therefore generates less scheduling overhead.

I use gcc with flags -fopenmp -O3. With bigger time per task (10 ms) the first code ran in 39 seconds where the second ran in 29 seconds. So there is big difference. However I almost never see approaches with if(0) in recursive openmp tasks.

"I executed with 8 threads." You are aware your first approach peaks at 254 concurrent threads, versus 7 concurrent threads in your second approach?

First of all, because only the 2nd and 3rd call can run in parallel if we do the math I do not think we can achieve a speedup of more than 8 times. However maybe the first code just spawns so many tasks that only with 254 threads it can come close to that theoretical upper bound, whereas the second code can come close to it with just 7 threads because we spawn less tasks? I am still a bit confused of what exactly happens on the second code though, how are tasks scheduled etc. If we do not include if(0) the recursion does not follow the correct ordering...

I am not able to reproduce this problem on both GCC 13.2.0 and Clang 16.0.6 (so two different OpenMP runtime and two different compilers) on my PC with an i5-9600KF CPU (6 cores) and Debian on Linux 6.5.10-1. Removing #pragma omp task if(0) has no impact (as expected). The variation of execution time is +/- few ms on 18205 ms in average (apparently just the statistical noise). Can you provide more information so to track any difference in the environment?

Besides, note that adding another #pragma omp task in the first code can might cause too many tasks to be scheduled (but honestly I doubt this is a problem here with so few task). Not creating a task in the second code can cause scheduling starvation regarding the actual scheduler used (dependent of the compiler and the environment which are not provided).

@RuudHelderman No, there are not 254 threads. This is tasks, not threads. There are only OMP_NUM_THREADSthreads created once in theparallel for` section, no more. Tasks are scheduled by OpenMP threads during scheduling points (e.g. end of an OpenMP parallel section). Tasks are generally more lightweight than threads when it comes to creation and scheduling (dependent of the runtime and the task context though).

@JérômeRichard I can reproduce the trends with gcc 13.2.0 on Ubuntu 24.04 for execution with 4 and 8 threads. For me, removing #pragma omp task if(0) surprisingly has an effect. With initial level=7, the code calls usleep 4**7=16k times. So, the expected serial execution time is 16.4 seconds. Compiled without OpenMP, the code executes in about 18 seconds and I get similar execution time with OMP_NUM_THREADS=1. With 4 threads, I see about 5 seconds execution time, but 11 seconds when leaving out the #pragma omp task if(0).

The first code executes in about 7.5s. Changing the second task to task if(0) brings down the execution time to 5s. Removing the second task directive at all, increases the execution time to 11 seconds, just like for removing task if(0) from the second code.

@Joachim I also tried changing in the first code the second task to task if(0) and i get the same time with the second code, so it improved

@JérômeRichard I use wsl2 with Ubuntu 22.04 and gcc 11.4.0 but I do not think it has to do with the compiler.  Somehow #pragma omp task if(0) can affect the execution time, but I struggle to find proper examples online where someone suggested task if(0) as a way to make a code run faster...

I finally reproduced this on an Ubuntu machine with an AMD CPU on both GCC and Clang. I probably just missed the -fopenmp in the command-line on the other machine so I am dumb (it was time to sleep for me -- too late ^^"). Sorry.

The point is  impacts #pragma omp taskwait waits the completion of child tasks of the current task and the current task is not the same when there are tasks created with #pragma omp task if(0). This means that having no later directive results in an over-synchronization causing a higher execution time (certainly due to less parallelism). Indeed, the #pragma omp taskwait directive waits for more tasks in this case (especially true tasks without the if(0)).

Example with 2 levels
To better understand what happens, we can analyze what the function exactly do at the level 2 (and increase the delay to 10_000 so we can see any difference at run time). Here is the flatten code:
void recursive_task_level2()
{
    #pragma omp task if(0)
    {
        #pragma omp task if(0)
        {
            usleep(10000);

            #pragma omp task
            usleep(10000);
        
            usleep(10000);

            #pragma omp taskwait
            
            usleep(10000);
        }

        #pragma omp task // <----- [A] WAITED TASK
        {
            #pragma omp task if(0)
            {
                usleep(10000);

                #pragma omp task
                usleep(10000);
            
                usleep(10000);

                #pragma omp taskwait
                
                usleep(10000);
            }
        }
    
        #pragma omp task if(0) // <----- [B] IMPORTANT ONE
        {
            usleep(10000);

            #pragma omp task
            usleep(10000);
        
            usleep(10000);

            #pragma omp taskwait // <----- [C]
            
            usleep(10000);
        }

        #pragma omp taskwait
        
        #pragma omp task if(0)
        {
            usleep(10000);

            #pragma omp task
            usleep(10000);
        
            usleep(10000);

            #pragma omp taskwait
            
            usleep(10000);
        }
    }
}

Here is the idea: if [B] is present, then [C] does not wait for [A] because it is not a child task anymore; however, if [B] is not present, then [C] wait for [A], that is, before waiting 10 ms.
This effect is confirmed by running this code both with/without [B] and with/without all other #pragma omp task if(0). In this case, the only directive that matters is [B] and commenting [B] does increase the execution time by precisely 10 ms (92 vs 102 ms). This proves the hypothesis is true.
With more levels, the amount of parallelism is strongly reduced due to the over-syncronization and the additional time should also be accumulated on the critical path (certainly exponentially) resulting in a huge execution overhead.

Solutions
To avoid waiting on more task than expected, you can:

create tasks in #pragma omp taskgroup section so all tasks created in the group (and there children recursively) are waited at the end of the section.
use task dependencies so tasks only wait what is strictly needed; note that taskwait also support dependency so you can wait just a subset of the tasks created in the current task.
use #pragma omp task if(0) so to control what tasks are waited by #pragma omp taskwait; see the @Joachim's answer; though the intent is rather counter-intuitive for readers (people expect this to have no impact).

Be aware that task dependencies only work on sibling tasks (i.e. tasks create in a same parent task): you cannot create a dependency between a task and the children of a sibling task (or even sibling tasks of the parent tasks of a given tasks). This is a rather-strong limitation when you use recursive tasking.
Also be aware that dependencies often introduce a small overhead (typically dependent of the number of dependencies).

I'm not convinced that it is just an implementation synchronization overhead. Running with clang-18, I see the same execution times for all the different versions (including a version where I only have a task for the second recursive_task function call). Same, if I compile with gcc, but link libomp. How would you explain the effect of only making the second task if(0). I see the same performance, but it does not group the tasks.

I did use Clang 18 (18.1.3) on my AMD machine to analyze the timings on both the level 2 and level 7 use-case. The level 2 is proven by experimental checks as shown in the answer. I did reproduce this with both Clang and GCC for both levels. I run the program 10 times and analyzed the media time (while showing other timings so to be careful about the statistical execution noise which can be sneaky and make you think two code are sometimes equivalent performance-wise when run only once). Did you maybe forgot -fopenmp like I did before :p ?

@Joachim By the way, note OMP_DISPLAY_ENV is different for Clang and GCC on my AMD machine showing I use 2 different runtimes (sad the name of the runtime is not printed though so IDK if this is the same overall implementation -- only the version which are "201611" for Clang and "201511" for GCC). ldd shows that this is libgomp for GCC and libomp for Clang as expected.

@Joachim Can you share the code you are testing and your runtime version? Just to be 100% sure I understand what your are testing and possibly reproduce it. If I understand correctly what you are saying, you see a different behavior on the same code between libomp and libgomp independently of the compiler used, right?

I missunderstood what you mean with over-synchronization. I thought the additional synchronization would cause runtime overhead. But actually, the [A] task accounts for 30ms, while the [B] task only collects 20ms before the taskwait. So, [A]+[B] account for 40ms, if the taskwait in [B] needs to wait for [A] and [A]+[B] account for 30ms, if they can run fully concurrently. In the first code from OP, we have two tasks where the second task provides similar scoping to your task marked with [B]. Your observation explains my  7.5->11 increase for deleting the task, but not 7.5->5 for marking if(0)

Ok so not adding [B] will make taskwait have effect to tasks it should not normally have effect and including [B] prevents that. Regarding the initial problem, what is the most elegant way to write the code, so it is obvious that we want at each level of recursion first to execute the 1st call and wait for it, then execute in parallel 2nd and 3rd and wait for them and only then go for the 4th execution?

@hpc_beginner I added some alternative solution so fix that. I tried both the taskgroup-based and depend-based solutions and both was working well on the level 2 example (I did not test the level 7 so far).

@hpc_beginner I personally like using task dependencies in my codes since this is IMHO more flexible than recursive tasks and this does not mix well with recursive tasks in many cases so I tend to avoid recursive tasking though recursive tasks tends to be better suited for recursive functions (simpler). Sometimes, you can flatten the task graph by "linearizing" calls (i.e. using for loops) and using dependencies arrays (cumbersome to do manually, but very powerful/flexible). The later avoid nearly all over-synchronization (but the tasking overhead is often bigger). There is no free lunch ;)

OpenMP 6.0 introduces transparent task dependencies to allow building dependencies across ancestry levels. Look for import/export keywords. Since 6.0 is just released, there is no implementation yet.

The following variant of the first code has the same critical path as the first code:
void recursive_task(int level)
{   
    if (level == 0){
        usleep(1000);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        recursive_task(level-1);

        #pragma omp task
        {
             recursive_task(level-1);
        }
        
        #pragma omp task if(0)
        {
             recursive_task(level-1);
        }
        
        #pragma omp taskwait
        
        recursive_task(level-1);
    }
}

Due to the taskwait following the two tasks, execution time will not improve, if a thread different from the encountering thread would execute the second task. Using if(0) encourages the OpenMP runtime to execute this task immediately rather than possibly scheduling other tasks first. Using if(0) rather than dropping the task construct completely ensures the scoping as described in @JérômeRichard's answer.
Overall, the serial version of the code has a lower bound for the execution time of 4**7 = 16384 ms. Considering that one out of four function calls at each level can execute concurrenly, the lower bound for parallel execution should be 3**7 = 2187 ms, which can be reached with 8 threads and will not improve afterwards.

So just forcing Openmp runtime to execute this task immediately rather than placing it to the pool of tasks has that big difference here? Do you think this is expected?

@hpc_beginner for me the effect with clang is smaller, so the task scheduling strategy has certainly an impact. Our hpc cluster is on maintenance over the weekend. I'll do some experiments adding priorities and using more threads once the system is up next week.

I am an undergrad student and I run most of these demo experiments on my laptop or at a cluster we have at university and the differences are remarkable. So with that logic openmp task based parallel codes like the classic fibonacci example, can also get faster adding if(0) at the second task?

that is to say every time we want to use recursion and we want to have 2 calls that should be synchronized, we should try adding if(0) to one of the tasks and as a result keep the one task for the current thread and give only the other call to the rest of the threads?

@hpc_beginner for algorithms with low cost for the leaves, many tutorials suggest using if(0) at some recursion depth. The latest openmp examples document contains an example that significantly reduces the cost for the ends of recursion by combining the metadirective directive in combination with a simple boolean template.

First, I am comparing the code provided in @Joachim with or without the if(0) clause at second task. When using GCC 11.4.0 I see differences, but when using Clang 14.0.0 the two codes run in about the same time (of course adding if(0) gives some slight edge but not big differences). Then I tried some stupid experiments like the one below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct timeval t1, t2;

void recursive_task(int level)
{   
    //printf("%d\n", level);
    
    if (level == 0){
        sleep(1);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                recursive_task(level-1);
            }
             #pragma omp task 
            {
                recursive_task(level-1);
            }
            #pragma omp taskwait
    }
}

int main()
{
    double time;

    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
#pragma omp single
        {
            recursive_task(2);
        }
    }

    gettimeofday(&t2, 0);

    time = (double)((t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000000;
    printf("%.4f\n", time);

    return 0;
}

Now this should run in about 1 second but in GCC this sometimes runs in about 2 seconds and very rarely (at least in my laptop) runs in 1 second so it does not always manage to schedule correctly and take advantage of the enough threads. This is a very strange inconsistency. I think there are some issues with GCC with OpenMP scheduler, like a bug or something. When using if(0) at second task it always seems to run in 1 second, as expected, but normally it should not be that huge difference just adding if(0).
On the other hand, with Clang, both with and without if(0) it runs in 1 second. I think there is some bug in GCC, can someone confirm that the bug presented above can also be reproduced, and I am not crazy?
